# Notepad ++ Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to replace

```
removeUnderline(getPlayerName(*));
```

With

```
getPlayerNameWM(*);
```

While * is something between the brackets.

For example, replace `removeUnderline(getPlayerName("Daniel"));`

With `getPlayerNameWM("Daniel");`

Comment: What language?  And what does this have to do with notepad++?

Comment: Have you tried solving this problem?

Comment: This is Squirrel. It's C-based.
I tried to solve it by manually changing every single thing, but I'm missing loads of brackets. I'm using Notepad++ in order to make a replacement to all files in a folder (about 400 matches, 9 files).
Is there any other efficient way to replace those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find : `removeUnderline\(getPlayerName\(([^)]*)\)\);`

Replace : `getPlayerNameVM\($1\);`

Comment: It doesn't work, seems like 0 occurrences were replaced. Thank you for your efforts and will to help!

Comment: @Ariel: make sure that you don't have any extra space in the find pattern. regex check is enabled right?

Comment: @Ariel: try this :`removeUnderline\s*\(\s*getPlayerName\s*\(([^)]*)\)\);` for space issues

Comment: Managed to fix it. Thank you very very much Prince John! You saved me.